# Не работает CPaintDC при SetMapMode(MM_LOENGLISH)

Tags: winapi, graphics, mfc, shape

```
void CHildView::OnPaint() {
  CPaintDC dc(this);
  dc.SetMapMode(MM_LOENGLISH);
  dc.Ellipse(50,50,100,100); 
}
```

Если не использую `SetMapMode()`, то эллипс рисуется. Если использую — пустой экран.

Почему так? :(

Comment: Любое двухмерное преобразование можно описать в виде двух составляющих: поворота и последующего перемещения. Компоненты *dx* и *dy* как раз и описывают перемещение.

Comment: @Arhad поворот == перемещение, т.е. при повороте всем точкам задаются новые х, у. Имеется ввиду перемещение точек после поворота?

Comment: `перемещение точек после поворота` — именно.

Comment: `поворот == перемещение` — не совсем. При повороте точки её «отклонение» от координатных осей прямо пропорционально расстоянию до этих осей. В случае же простого перемещения отклонение константно и от расстояния не зависит.

Comment: К слову, любая трансформация описывается как *x_новый = a₁₁ * x + a₁₂ * y + dx, y_новый = a₂₁ * x + a₂₂ * y + dy*, где числа *a* — это длина проекции на оси после вращения. Как видите, *dx* и *dy* прибавляются отдельно, то есть поворот на них не влияет. Иными словами, каким бы поворот ни был, простое смещение из начала координат не изменяется.

Comment: Зачем затёрли первую часть вопроса? Теперь мои комментарии не имеют никакого смысла.

Comment: @Arhad Пояснение к первым комментариям. Первоначально не рисовалась фигура при использовании SetWorldTransform, предполагал, что это из-за того, что не понял как работает SetWorldTrasform(hdc, xform), думал, что дело в xform.eDx, xform.eDy. Однако потом заметил что даже без него не рисуется. К слову, Проблема была в том, что после поворота с SetMapMode, по- прежнему передавал координаты для рисования (50,50,100,100), но не учёл, что в новой СК будут новые координаты для правого верхнего и левого нижнего, т.е. упустил, что SetMapMode задал новую СК, относился как к повороту СК.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну вот же у него:

```
dc.SetMapMode(MM_LOENGLISH);
dc.Ellipse(50,50,100,100);
```

а надо

```
dc.SetMapMode(MM_LOENGLISH);
dc.Ellipse(50,-50,100,-100);
```